# Query within php isn't working

Tags: php, mysql

I am not very experienced with php and mysql. The plan was to create a textbox, within this textbox you could write whatever you want. And then the text within the textbox would be updated to a database.

It says the mistake is within this line:

```
$sql = "UPDATE members SET tekst='$_POST['chat']' WHERE id='$_SESSION['id']'";
```

This line is within the next code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    session_start();

    if(!session_is_registered(gebruikersnaam))
        {
            header("location:form.php");
        }
?>

<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $servername = "mysql.hostfree.nl";
        $username = "u411684910_info";
        $password = "rsg2015";
        $dbname = "u411684910_note";

        $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        $sql = "UPDATE members SET tekst='$_POST['chat']' WHERE id='$_SESSION['id']'";

        if (!$conn) 
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error());
        }

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        {
            echo "New record created successfully";
            echo $_SESSION["id"];
        } 

        else 
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error($conn);
        }

        mysql_close($conn);

    }
    else
    {
?>
        <form action="succes.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="chat">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
<?php
    }   
?>
```

Thanks in advance,

Gyon

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: What's the actual error? Welcome to S/O. Quotes maybe?

Comment: `mysqli` is also acceptable if you use it correctly i.e. use prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and parametrized queries.

Comment: Your actual error is trying to put array access directly into a string, you need to surround it with braces `{$_POST['chat']}`. **BUT** thats not the correct solution, you should look in to tadman's advice.

Comment: Might it be, that mysql is deprecated and it should be mysqli?

Comment: you are `updating` instead of `inserting`

Comment: Oh yeah, not to mention you are inconsistently using both. mysql_connect and mysqli_query

Comment: Thank you,  dan08, for your comment, I will change that too.

Comment: @Gyon. Just remove single quotes inside `$_POST`. As long as you already included in a string with double quotes. like this: `$sql = "UPDATE members SET tekst='$_POST[chat]' WHERE id='$_SESSION[id]'";`. Did you notice the difference? =)

Comment: Yes. I do @bcesars. Thank you all guys. I hope I am able to fix it. Although I will have to take a look at PDO later. Because it is a school assignment to use PHP and Mysql together.

Comment: Those look like actual login credentials. If they are, you better change those now.

Comment: I did, noticed it directly

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add to a variable those following values

```
 $session = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION["id"]);
 $chat = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['chat']);
```

then the query

```
$sql = "UPDATE members SET tekst='$chat' WHERE id='$session'";
```

Comment: I have those in another code connected to this one. Is that also acceptable?

Comment: This will fail. Want to know why? Read up on the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - Plus, don't use CAPS; it's considered as "shouting".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mysql_query. It's deprecated.
But try this:

```
$chat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chat']);
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE members SET tekst = '$chat' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Gyon,

It appears that the problem is really with the following line:

$sql = "UPDATE members SET tekst='$_POST['chat']' WHERE id='$_SESSION['id']'";

Exactly the problem with quotes:

```
tekst='$_POST['chat']' WHERE id='$_SESSION['id']'
```

You need to change this to be something like the following:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE members SET tekst="$_POST['chat']" WHERE id="$_SESSION['id']"';
```

Alternatively, I'd recommend to have the following:

$chat = $_POST['chat'];

$sessionId = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = "UPDATE members SET tekst='$chat' WHERE id='$sessionId'";

Answer (score 0):

There are so many discrepancies in your code that needs mentioning, But, first things first. Mind your quotation marks.

```
"UPDATE members SET tekst='".$_POST['chat']."' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
```

This will look more readable in your text editor.

And as mentioned by other people, **dont use** mysql extension anymore.

Use Mysqli or PDO which are more **safer** to use, as they have escaping functions and PDO escapes your strings for you.